# Google Drive Api Java Quickstart compile error

Tags: java, api, google-drive-api

I am attempting to use Google Drive Service Java API to upload files. I am using a `Quickstart.java` example to figure out what I need to code. I am getting a compiler error. Please assist in resolving my compiler error.

```
Quickstart.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
             .setPageSize(10)
             ^
  symbol:   method setPageSize(int)
  location: class Drive.Files.List
Quickstart.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getFiles()
  location: variable result of type FileList
Quickstart.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable file of type File
3 errors
```

I might be using an out of date library, but I went to Google's REST website
and download the latest that they had.

Here is the code:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
             .setPageSize(10)
             .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
             .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: pasting the compiler errors is ONE essential part of resolving such issues. The other part (missing) ... the source code that gives the problems! If you want us to help you, add that missing part ...

Comment: The **other** important essential thing: to be around after putting up a question.

Comment: Thanks for your response GhostCat. Do apologize for not being available.

Comment: Formatted the question, and removed unnecessary text

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what exactly is wrong; just explain what is going on.

Example - the compiler complains about:

```
Quickstart.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
         .setPageSize(10)
```

The corresponding code is:

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
```

Lets see what you got. `service` is an instance of the *Drive* class of Google's API. When you start looking into javadoc, yep, that class offers a method files(); and the result of that call ... allows to call list().

And `list()` is supposed to return an object of class [List](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.List.html).

Now you turn to the javadoc for that class ... and surprise: there is **no** method called *setPageSize()*.

So, long story short: the compiler is telling you, that a method that you are trying to call on some object doesn't exist! You reaction then is:

1. Like I did: dive into the depths of that call
2. Look into the documentation for that class

in order to figure what is going on.

I am not an expert in that Google API, but my **guess** is: this is some sort of version incompatibility. Probably you copied your Quickstart source code from somewhere ... but **this** source code is simply not compatible with the version of the Google API that your compiler sees in your project setup.

So, the real answer here is:

1. Ensure that example code *matches* the API version that you are using
2. Trust the compiler messages.

And seriously: if you need other people to explain such basic stuff to you, then you should **first** spend some hours learning about them; for example by working some basic Java tutorials. There is no point in trying to use advanced Google APIs when you need other people to *understand* what is going on.

And beyond that: you **never** just put down some code from somewhere. The minimum thing you do before even trying to run: read it completely; and understand each and every call in there.

I hope this gives you enough ideas to resolve your actual issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not a Java developer, but know enough to ask a question in hopes that someone could help.

Comment: You are welcome; if you find my answer sufficient, please consider accepting at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and then realized I had accidentally downloading the V2 library instead of the V3 library.

Make sure you've downloaded the most current library (as of this post can be found in [Google Drive Platform: Downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/downloads).)